# How do I center a CrystalReportViewer on the screen?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, crystal-reports

All of the objects on the screen are centered with the exception of the CrystalReportViewer.

Does the CrystalReportViewer not work with CSS?

Here's my CSS class that I'm using for this part of the page:

```
.reportForm {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #efeeef;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}
```

The report is all the way to the left of the screen, I just want to center it.

Again, all other controls are centered on the screen.

The report is also embedded on a paragraph tag.

Here's the actual control:

```
<form runat="server" class="reportForm">
<p>
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="crvSchedules" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True" DisplayStatusbar="False" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" EnableDrillDown="False" EnableParameterPrompt="False" EnableTheming="False" EnableToolTips="False" HasCrystalLogo="False" HasDrilldownTabs="False" HasDrillUpButton="False" HasGotoPageButton="False" HasPageNavigationButtons="False" HasSearchButton="False" HasToggleGroupTreeButton="False" HasToggleParameterPanelButton="False" HasZoomFactorList="False" Height="1153px" ToolPanelView="None" Width="868px" GroupTreeImagesFolderUrl="" ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="" ToolPanelWidth="200px" HasExportButton="False" HasPrintButton="False" />
</p>
</form>
```

This is the ENTIRE CSS file:

```
.reportForm {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #efeeef;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

.site-title {
    color: #c8c8c8;
    font-family: Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 2.3em;
}

input[type="submit"],
    input[type="button"],
    button {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        border: 1px solid #787878;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 6px;
        margin-right: 8px;
        width: auto;
    }
```

Comment: There's not enough code here to reproduce the problem (where's the *generated* HTML?  template code will not be useful here).

Comment: I added the control to my original post.

Comment: This is *all* of the CSS that controls this element?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing else on the page.

Comment: There *has* to be more CSS influencing this element, because it looks centered to me:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/sdcjypek

Comment: I added the entire CSS file to my OP. the other classes are irrelevant because the CrystalReportViewer is not part of those ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out what the issue was with this so I just put the report in a table and centered it.